# Минимальная длина - 10 символов

Tags: javascript

```js
function someFunc(){
 var integer = document.getElementById('max').childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
someFunc();
```

```html
<form>
<textarea type="email"></textarea>
<p id="max">Минимальная длина 10  символов</p>
</form>
```

Есть стандартный input как сделать чтобы при вводе на textarea из числа 10 в котором находится в теге p вычитывалось по каждой введенной букве а когда 10 будет равен 0 тег p исчез.

Comment: Если вкратце, то повесить функцию на событие `change()`, которая будет проверять кол-во символов, обновлять тег `p` и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так, ваш пример конечно был совсем далек от решения

```js
function someFunc(){
 var integer = document.getElementById('email').value.toString().length;
    var last = 10 - integer;

    if (last <= 0) {
        document.getElementById('max').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('max').style.display = 'block';
    }


    document.getElementById('last').innerHTML = last;
}
someFunc();
```

```html
<form>
<textarea type="email" id="email" onKeyup="someFunc()"></textarea>
<p id="max">Минимальная длина <span id="last">10</span>  символов</p>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное